# In Matplotlib, how to get same math text font as before an update

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, anaconda, tex

I recently updated my `matplotlib` package from version 1.4.3 to 1.5.1 with `conda`.  I noticed once I did this that my math text font changed, at least for one character, written in TeX as \AA. Before the update, when I would write $\AA$ I would get this (ignore the parentheses):

[image]

which is exactly what I want.  However, after the update, $\AA$ looked like this (again ignore the parentheses):

[image]

The angstrom is not italicized and the circle is a bit separated from the A.  I then used $\mathrm{\AA}$ and got (again, sorry, ignore the parentheses):

[image]

with the circle still separated from the A.

I would like the first picture shown above to be the character that appears in my plots.  How can I get \AA to appear like that all the time, short of going back to the earlier version of `matplotlib`?  Is there a way to do it in my current version?

I know in LaTeX \AA can be written outside of math mode to produce the desired character but in `matplotlib` I have only been able to get it to work in math mode.  I am not familiar with how to, or even if I can, get non-math mode LaTeX appearing in my axis labels.

**Relevant note**: I have written in my `~/.matplotlib/matplotlib` file `font.family : serif` and `mathtext.fontset : custom`.  However, I had my suspicions that `matplotlib` is no longer looking at that file (perhaps something with the new update) and indeed [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) don't seem to reference by default a `~/.matplotlib/matplotlib` file.  When I `mv` that file to the directory I am using `matplotlib` in and rename it to `matplotlibrc` (as per what the docs specify `matplotlib` will look for) I get the following for $\AA$ (again ignore the parentheses):

[image]

This is okay but I would still like something closer the the first picture shown above.

Comment: Any chance that the difference is `usetex==True` in the `rc`? Another option might be using `\text{\AA}` for text mode, but you might have to load amsmath or amssymb into the preamble for that...I'm not sure.

Comment: please open a bug report on mpl for this.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, preamble? I'm used to preambles for LaTeX documents, but I've never heard of using one for `matplotlib`. How does that work?

Comment: See the `text.latex.preamble` part [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file), just another attribute in the `rc`. Note that it's explicitly discouraged as a feature to use, but I've had success with it in the past (in very simple use cases).